# Java UCanAccess doesn't detect all items

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess

I have a problem. I use this query:

```
SELECT prodeje.datum, 
       prodeje.prodejce, 
       prodeje.pocet, 
       prodeje.cena, 
       produkty.autor_music, 
       produkty.autor_text, 
       produkty.skladba, 
       produkty.isrc, 
       produkty.cd, 
       produkty.ean 
FROM   prodeje 
       INNER JOIN produkty 
           ON prodeje.id_produktu = produkty.id
```

But it doesn't return all items. There should be 59 results but it skips (randomly) 9 results. When I tried the same query in Microsoft Access it worked...so I'm desperate.

I am using UCanAccess JDBC driver.

Comment: Try changing the `INNER JOIN` for `LEFT JOIN` and see if it recover all results.

Comment: Can you upload an Access database file containing those two tables to a site like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com/) and then post the download link in a comment here so we can try to recreate the issue?

Comment: Of course, here it is:
http://wikisend.com/download/392154/data_prodej.mdb

Comment: And I tried LEFT JOIN, it doesn't work too. When I used the old JDBS driver there was no problem. So I think it might be caused by the UCanAcces

Comment: Oh I see..when I try to select all from produkty, it doesnt.. Those 9 results are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, (maybe) ghost  caught.
This problem has already been reported (but unfortunatly nobody provided me the corrupted mdb):
http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/0b85dea2/ and it's unrelated to the SQL engine.
This issue is at a  lower level than UcanAccess (IO problem because of format errors in your mdb). It look like Ms Access can work fine despite those errors, while Jackcess (the library used by UCanAccess) doesn't.
Your mdb version is 1997 (partially supported in read only by UCanAccess) and if you converted it in a later version, all would work fine with UCanAccess.
Also, the use of   the MS Access  "Repair and Fix" tool, should fix the issue as well.

Comment: +1 I agree that this is a case of a somewhat damaged Access 97 file. I can confirm that if one does a "Repair" and then a "Compact" in Access 97 (they were separate operations in that version) then UCanAccess will report the correct number of rows in the [produkty] table. (UCanAccess could only "see" 38 rows before the repair/compact in Access 97, but it could "see" all 54 rows afterwards.)

Comment: This issue, due to a misalignment between table metadata and data in damaged mdb/accdb, has been solved in UCanAccess 2.0.9.