# Multivalue WHERE in select statement in UCanAccess is returning incorrect results

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ucanaccess

This is a continuation of my [previous question about using multivalue in UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373126/workaround-in-ucanaccess-for-multi-value-fields-incompatible-data-type-in-conv).  I believe that I have set up my query as is done in [the ComplexTest.java example](http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/code/HEAD/tree/ucanaccess/trunk/src/test/java/net/ucanaccess/test/ComplexTest.java), and I have Repaired & Compacted my Access database as is [suggested in another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975014/java-ucanaccess-doesnt-detect-all-items).
  I am able to correctly select multivalue fields using getObject, but when I use setObject with either a SingleValue or SingleValue[] on the question marks in a PreparedStatement with a WHERE clause the returned result set does not reflect limits of the WHERE. Instead of returning a few hundred records it returns the full table or combination of tables.
  Does anyone have any advice?
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import net.ucanaccess.complex.SingleValue;

public class WhereQuery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String sql = "SELECT [A-CCBC-BaseDrawings-1].* FROM [TableA] WHERE ((([TableA].Place)=?));";

      File database = new File("/Users/George/Java/WhereQueryProject/Database.accdb"); // Access database   
      Connection conn = null;   // The connection object
      try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");  // Sets up the UCanAccess driver
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+database.getPath());    // connects to the MS Access database
      }     
      catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
      }

      PreparedStatement ps = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;
      try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setObject(1,new SingleValue[]{new SingleValue("Baltimore")});
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
      }
      catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      FromAccess.printResultSet(rs, sql); // a method for printing result sets
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. It's a bug. I'm analyzing and I'll let you know my findings asap.

Comment: I've been  a bit naive in not seeing this issue.
In the 2.0.9(available, hopefully, next week) ucanaccess will support:
SELECT * FROM [TableA] WHERE Equals([TableA].Place,?) 
In this  specific case the access syntax won't be supported in ucanaccess.
You'll be able to use functions instead of operators like =.
All that will be documented in the ucanaccess web site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention to this.  It will be very helpful.

Comment: As I said, the 2.0.9 adds the support to Equals, EqualsIgnoreOrder and Contains functions to allow a basic filtering on complex type columns (e.g., attachments, multivalue and so on).
See the documentation in the getting started section of the UCanAccess website.